# How to update the GridView after checking some checkbox inside the GridView Fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an intranet web application using ASP.NET. Now, I need to develop a training record for my department. The department consists of the four groups. For that, I developed this record as following: I used a Repeator and inside it I put GridView since I have three different types of training courses. And I used a HiddenField to determine the ID for each training course type. For retrieving the data from the database, I used the StoredProcedure. Everything works fine and well after this long task.

Now, I need to set these GridViews for updating by the admin. So since I have 
a lot of employees and a lot of courses in each GridView, I think the best 
way to update the GridView is to show the blank fields as checkboxes and when 
the Admin wants to update the record of one of the employees, all what he 
needs to do is just checking the checkboxes and click update button. **I could 
be able to show the empty fields as checkboxes but now I don't know how to 
post the value of checking the checkbox to the database.**

The scenario that I am looking for it is to make the system check every 
checkbox in each GridView, if it is already checked before, leave it as it 
is. If it was empty and it is just checked now, it should be added to the 
database in the record of the employee.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("GroupID")%>' />

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport">
                                    <%--FilterExpression="[Division] like '{0}%' and [Organization] like '{1}%'">--%>

                    <%--<FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="Division" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlOrganization" Name="Organization" 
                                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>--%>

                    <SelectParameters>
                        <%--ControlParameter is linked to the HiddenField above to generate different GridView based on different values 
                            of GroupID--%>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="GroupID" PropertyName="Value" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                                AllowSorting="True" 
                                CellPadding="3" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                                CssClass="mGrid"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                                RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black"/> 
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

                        <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                           SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM courses">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
        <br /><br />
```

The Code-Behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                // Check if the cell vlaue = Yes
                // if it is Yes, the cell will be colored with Light Green 
                if (c.Text.Equals("Yes"))
                {
                    c.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                }
            }    
        }

        // The following is for changing the color of headers in each GridView based on the value of the HiddenFild 
        // BTW, the value of the HiddenField is the value of the GroupID in Group Table in the Database 
        else if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header){
            switch (((HiddenField)((GridView)sender).Parent.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value)
            {
                case "1":
                    for (int i = 5; i &lt; e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                    break;

                case "2":
                    for (int i = 5; i &lt; e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
                    break;

                case "3":
                    for (int i = 5; i &lt; e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                    break;
            }
        }}


        //For inserting checkboxes inside all courses buttons
        protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e){
            GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
            foreach (GridViewRow objRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 5; i &lt; objRow.Cells.Count; i++){
                    CheckBox chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                    objRow.Cells[i].Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);
                    if (objRow.Cells[i].BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen)
                        chkCheckBox.Checked = true;
                }

            }
        }


        //For updating the GridView (Save Button)
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

**UPDATE:**
I modified the btnSave_Click button to be as following:

```
//For updating the GridView (Save Button)
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
            // Are there checked boxes?
            List<int> CheckBoxList = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int courseid = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[i][0];
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox");
                if (checkBox.Checked)
                {
                    CheckBoxList.Add(courseid);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I got the following error:
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'

I don't know why I got this error. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: could you add a field dynamically to the gridview that would display updated by admin

Comment: No need for that. All what I want is to recognize the checking checkboxes and update the records in the database

Comment: Oh.. ok then you could do a foreach loop and check for the checkbox and from there do some additional coding if there is a checkbox that is checked let me send you a sample

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change this to work for what you need, but if you want to check for items that are checked in the GridView Control try this:

```
 List<int> CheckBoxList = new List<int>();  
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count; i++)  
 {  
     int yourColumnId = (int)GridView.DataKeys[i][0];  
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView.Rows[i].FindControl("The name of your CheckBox");  
     if (cb.Checked)  
     {  
         CheckBoxList.Add(productId);  
     }  
 }  
 // Do something with CheckBoxList
```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your answer. Could you please simplify it as my code above. I am new ASP.NET developer so forgive me if I am asking a lot

Comment: when are you wanting to check if the buttons are checked..? this same code will work in asp.net you would just need to replace or put it inside of the right event handler. for that part I am not sure where you are wanting to check for the check boxes